# unable to understand fluentd/td-agent sending mechanism

Tags: logging, rabbitmq, amqp, fluentd, ubuntu-15.04

Hey I am working with fluentd recently. So the thing is I am making an environment where fluentd from different servers will send logs to central system with fluentd installed where the processing of the logs will be done.

But I am stuck at this point. I'm unable to understand the mechanism it uses to transfer logs from one node to another. Also I want to use some messaging queue like rabbitmq here to do this for me.

I'm unable to find suitable answer for this question on google and i dont find the documentation very suitable for me to understand everything about fluentd and its plugins. and since my networking concepts are not that strong, some things go over my head. Also I found out that it sends logs to treasure-data by default and there is a way to disable that. I want some understanding on how to use rabbitmq to do this for me.

Comment: Please give me some links where I can read more about fluentd and clarify my doubts. I would love it if you guys help me out in understanding the architecture and mechanism behind this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@repeatedly Thanks for your efforts. I already did the reading of the documentation. Its documentation needs some more work.

Found the solution. fluentd collector sends the log directly using tcp protocol. I have configured my fluentd to use kafka as a messaging queue. fluentd collector collects the logs from the log files and send them to the kafka server from where they should be sent to elasticsearch. So used another fluentd layer to collect logs from kafka and forward them to elasticsearch. It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

- Overview: http://www.fluentd.org/architecture
- Event Life cycle: http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/life-of-a-fluentd-event
- Configuration document: http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/config-file
- How to manage plugins: http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/plugin-management
- Output overview: http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/output-plugin-overview
- Buffer overview: http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/buffer-plugin-overview

Here are the basic documents and explain how fluentd works.
If you want to connect to rabbitmq, you can use amqp2 output plugin. To use amqp2 plugin is only 2 steps. Install it and add configuration.

```
// In fluentd gem
$ fluent-gem install fluent-plugin-amqp2
// In td-agent
$ /usr/sbin/td-agent-gem install fluent-plugin-amqp2
```

After that add amqp2 configuration to `fluent.conf` or `td-agent.conf`. Configuration is in plugin README: https://github.com/restorando/fluent-plugin-amqp#configuration.

BTW, could you tell me more details of `I'm unable to understand the mechanism`? It helps our documents :)